# Why does the UI update within Task.Run()

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, xamarin.forms, task, threadpool

I am developing a Xamarin.Forms application, where i am showing a label that updates its text on each second after starting a timer. The label's text value is bound to a ViewModel-property named "TimerValue". Its used to display the recording duration of an audio input. The timer method looks like the following:

```
    /// <summary>
    ///     The start recorder.
    /// </summary>
    private void StartTimer()
    {
        var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopwatch.Start();

        Device.StartTimer(
            new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 1, 0),
            () =>
                {
                    if (this.isRecording)
                    {
                        this.TimerValue = stopwatch.Elapsed.Seconds;
                        return true;
                    }

                    stopwatch.Stop();
                    this.TimerValue = 0;
                    return false;
                });
    }
```

The timer is started within a  Task.Run that is called on a UI-Event (GestureRecognizer.Tapped):

`await Task.Run(() => this.StartTimer()).ConfigureAwait(false);`

This code works, but why does it? Task.Run starts a new Thread on the ThreadPool, and the TimerValue sits on the UI-Thread. Shouldn't I have to call *Xamarin.Forms.Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread* to update the UI in this case?

**Why does the UI get updated if I set a UI-Bound Property within a Task.Run?**

Comment: Device.StartTimer is in the Xamarin.Forms namespace.  That makes it pretty likely to be a synchronous timer, similar to WPF's DispatcherTimer and Winforms' Timer.  Which makes it pretty like that it ticks on the UI thread.  Or never ticks at all, you'd know that.  The docs are entirely too vague about it.  Well, the shoe fits.

Comment: Ok, I thought it's ticking on the thread its called on... Because if i do not call Task.Run to start the timer, it will stop doing its work if i switch my page (the whole app uses a TabbedPage-Layout to display its data)

Comment: Also, WPF will allow *some* cross-thread updates. Xamarin may do the same, I don't know. Just because they *can* throw doesn't mean they *have* to throw. (IMO, cross-thread updates are still a bad idea, even if that particular kind happens to be allowed by a specific platform implementation).

Comment: @StephenCleary So would you suggest to use Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread to invoke the updates on the UI thread although my code is working in this sample?

Comment: I use `await` for results/errors, `IProgress<T>` for progress updates, and `SynchronizationContext` for subscriptions. It looks like yours is a subscription model, so I'd use `SynchronizationContext`.